# Using .env files with SPFx components - Undefined issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, error

I'm having a nightmare with using environment variables in my SPFx project. I have:

- a .env in the root of my project
- variables within this file all starting with REACT_APP_
- references to these variables using process.env.REACT_APP_
- restarted gulp, cleaned and built many times
- installed dotenv-webpack
- installed dotenv
- added 'node' to the types in tsconfig.json
- confirmed I can read process.env.NODE_ENV

Any variables inside my .env file just appear as 'undefined' when I try reading them and view with console.log.  Is there something I am missing?  I thought this was an easy thing to set up.

.env:

```
REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_LIST='text'
```

WebPart.ts:

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_LIST)
```

This reads as undefined.

Please help!

Comment: Try following this for `dotenv`: https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2020/03/05/using-env-files-in-sharepoint-framework-development/ and this for `DefinePlugin`: https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-handle-env-variable-using-defineplugin-in-spfx-solutions/. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You know what, I had looked at that link before, and dismissed it because I was getting errors in one of the files it tells you to create.   So I just looked back on it, searched on the errors, and fixed them with a missing semi colon!!  nice one for reassuring me it was the right way to go :)  All working now.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `process-env.js` like:

```
"use strict";
 
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
 
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "dev";
const dotEnvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), ".env");
 
const dotenvFiles = [
  `${dotEnvPath}.${NODE_ENV}.local`,
  `${dotEnvPath}.${NODE_ENV}`,
  NODE_ENV !== "test" && `${dotEnvPath}.local`,
  dotEnvPath
].filter(Boolean);
 
dotenvFiles.forEach(dotenvFile => {
  if (fs.existsSync(dotenvFile)) {
    require("dotenv-expand")(
      require("dotenv").config({
        path: dotenvFile
      })
    );
  }
});
 
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
process.env.NODE_PATH = (process.env.NODE_PATH || "")
  .split(path.delimiter)
  .filter(folder => folder && !path.isAbsolute(folder))
  .map(folder => path.resolve(appDirectory, folder))
  .join(path.delimiter);
 
const SPFX_ = /^SPFX_/i;
 
function getClientEnvironment() {
  const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
    .filter(key => SPFX_.test(key))
    .reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = process.env[key];
      return env;
    }, {});
 
  const stringified = {
    "process.env": Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
      return env;
    }, {})
  };
 
  return { raw, stringified };
}
 
module.exports = getClientEnvironment;
```

Next, append `gulpfile.js` and add this right before the build.initialize() call:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const getClientEnvironment = require("./process-env");
 
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
  additionalConfiguration: cfg => {
    let pluginDefine = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < cfg.plugins.length; i++) {
      var plugin = cfg.plugins[i];
      if (plugin instanceof webpack.DefinePlugin) {
        pluginDefine = plugin;
      }
    }
 
    const currentEnv = getClientEnvironment().stringified;
 
    if (pluginDefine) {
      pluginDefine.definitions = { ...pluginDefine.definitions, ...currentEnv };
    } else {
      cfg.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(currentEnv));
    }
 
    return cfg;
  }
});
```

Then you can use these variables like:

```
    
let apiBaseUrl = process.env.SPFX_WEBAPI_BASEURL;
```

**Reference**: [Using .env files in SharePoint Framework development](https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2020/03/05/using-env-files-in-sharepoint-framework-development/)

You can find full working code at: [demo-spfx-dotenv](https://github.com/dlw-digitalworkplace/demo-spfx-dotenv)

---

You can also use `DefinePlugin` for this. follow this: [How To Handle Env Variable Using DefinePlugin In SPFx Solutions](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-handle-env-variable-using-defineplugin-in-spfx-solutions/)

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to set this up, but I'm still getting undefined for my environment variables. Do you know if there's anything special I may need to do if my WebParts are React components? Thank you!